# How does a "theurge" prestige class mix with another spellcasting prestige class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

Scenario:

1. Given a Cleric 1 / Wizard 4 / Ur-Priest 2 (character level 7).  This character has both arcane and divine spellcasting and is assumed to meet the requirements for Mystic Theurge.
2. Takes 8 levels of Mystic Theurge (Cleric 1 / Wizard 4 / Ur-Priest 2 / Mystic Theurge 8), which advances the spellcasting of the Wizard base class to 14 and the Ur-Priest to 10.
3. Ur-Priest only has 10 class levels available to progress through.  **What happens on the next level of Mystic Theurge?**
4. The character is still only an Ur-Priest 2.  **What happens if the character takes a level of Ur-Priest, to advance to Ur-Priest 3, but the spellcasting level of the Ur-Priest is already Ur-Priest 10?**

Comment: I made an edit that I think clarifies point 3, please ensure the wording I chose is accurate for your question.

Answer (score -1):

Since the character has already acquired all of the spellcasting progression of Ur-Priest through Mystic Theurge when advancing Ur-Priest they would not be able to advance their spellcasting any further, but would acquire any other benefits of advancing Ur-Priest, such as save bonuses or BAB.

If this is the course of action that you're thinking about taking I'd instead recommend that after reaching Mystic Theurge 8 that you instead shift focus and start leveling up Wizard so that you can attain 9th level arcane spells.

Comment: Technically, to become an Ur-Priest, you have to become an ex-Cleric, which I think means you cannot advance the spellcasting ability of the Cleric via the Theurge because the Cleric level no longer has spellcasting ability.

Comment: Hmm... If that's the case then you're probably better off not advancing Ur-Priest and just leveling Wizard then so you can eventually get 9th level arcane spells.